# Background image repeating horizontally for one row

Tags: html, css, web-services

So this is some of the code I have:

```
html{
    background-image: url(blue.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

However, the image is repeating horizontally for the top row. After the top row, the image covers the page, with the top part being covered by the repeating first row.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you want to do actually?

Comment: where is your html?

Comment: Found the error, it was in my HTML, because I had tried setting the background from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use:

```
background-image: url(blue.jpg) no-repeat;
```

Comment: it should be background: url(blue.jpg) no-repeat; when using background-image you can have only url of the image and then add background-repeat:no-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are not resetting the background-image from somewhere else. As, when you try to change it from some other place, it resets all the other parameters. If you are changing it from somewhere else, make sure you set the     `background-repeat-x: no-repeat;` there also.